# Error Loading Google Cloud API OAuth Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up OAuth credentials for a web application to use Google Cloud APIs, everything seems to go fine when creating them but when I subsequently try to edit or view them I get an error saying

`Failed to load`

`There was an error while loading <URL to OAuth Client> Please try again.`

This obviously isn't much to go on but has anyone experienced anything similar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: There isn't any code, this is all through the Google Cloud web front end.

Comment: Is it happening on all the browsers or different credentials or different projects? Can you share more information on it and how to reproduce it? Maybe images or a sanitized video?